# In need of an autosuggest that returns an ID and firstname from the database

Tags: php, jquery, autosuggest

Hi I'm new to jquery, I'm doing a project for sending mails. 
In the project when i type in the firstname field of the sender it is meant to bring an autosuggest field.
The problem however is that what i need is the user's ID not the firstname(however I can't display the ID to the regular site user). 
I was thinking about storing the returned ID in an hidden field while at the same time storing the name in a table.

Please help me how do I go about this.

Problems
1. When I type in the text box it is able to return the firstname for the user to see.

2. Im not sure how to get the autosuggest to store the returned ID into an hidden field tag

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) plugin will come in handy for you..Have a look at this [blog](http://beski.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/jquery-php-mysql-ajax-autocomplete/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's autosuggest will work. You can return the data from your ajax call in the form of:

```
    [{"id":1, "label":"Joe"}, {"id":2,"label":"mike"}] (or you can use "value" instead of "label")
```

You can subscribe to the select event which has the following signature:

```
    function(event, ui){//ui.item.id will have the value you are looking for}
```

ui will have an item propety so you can use ui.item.id and grab back the id which you're looking for. Here is some more complete code. You'll need to substitute your url and however your php needs the search term.

```
  $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
     source: function(req, resp){
         $.getJSON(){
             "search.php",
             {searchTerm : req.term},
             function(data){
                resp(data);
             }
         }
     },
     select : function(ev, ui){
         alert(ui.item.id);
     }
  })
```

Comment: Im not too clear with how to tie the 3 blocks of codes together.

Comment: Hi @Tumi-- you don't really have to. The third block is the important one. You just need to make sure to send the data to the php correctly. And you need to make sure your php returns the data in the form of json data (in the format shown above). As the user starts typing into the autocomplete, the source method will get called. You use the req variable to get the "term" the user typed. You then make an ajax call to your page. The resp variable is a callback. You simple have to "call it back" and pass the results (in my function i called it data). The select is called when the user selects it.